# Solving a Recurrence Relation With Summation and Tau Function

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

How can I solve the following:

$$
T(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{d(n) - 2}T(v_i) + \sum_{i = d(n) - 1}^{n - 1}c + c'
$$

Where $d(n)$ is the **Tau** function, and **v** is the set of values dividing **n**.

e.g. $d(18) = 6$, and $v_0 = 1, v_1 = 2, v_2 = 3, v_3 = 6, v_4 = 9, v_5 = 18$.

**Edit:** From the discussion in the comments, it looks like the expression sought is:
$$
T(n) = \sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d < n}} T(d) + c (n - \tau(n)) + c'
$$

Comment: can you clarify what c and c' are?

Comment: $c$ and $c'$ are constants.

Comment: constants? then the second sum reduces to n-1-d(n) times that constant. As for the first term, have you looked at the Moebius inversion formula yet? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moebius_inversion

Comment: FYI, $v_i$ is an array containing the divisors of n, $v$ is not a function.

Comment: @vonbrand, what does $d|n$ mean?

Comment: $d|n$ means $d$ is a divisor of $n$.